# Can I use '!!' in aliases or scripts?

Tags: command-line, bash, alias

In the Terminal I can use `!!` which will reference my previous command.
 Is it possible to use this in an alias? I have tried it, but what happens is that the double exclamation marks are interpreted literally.

What I want to have possible is:

1. I enter some command
2. I type an alias that will include what was entered in step 1

If there is a solution using scripts that is also acceptable.

Comment: what is your main goal ?  add more options to last command ?

Comment: No my goal is to quickly type a long command I often use. In the middle of it is a long string that often is the previous command

Comment: it seems you want just `fc` command so it opens a text editor , because that is the easiest way to edit long commands. Let me add it to my post .  Also , maybe you could provide an example of command ?

Comment: Added an edit to my post

Comment: http://superuser.com/q/240180/337511

Answer (score 11):

The command that lists the last executed command is `fc -nl -1` . Using output substitution , we can add more parameters to the same content

```
$> ls /etc/passwd
/etc/passwd
$> $(fc -nl -1)  /etc/group                                                     
/etc/group  /etc/passwd
$>
```

Quoting , however, may be an issue with this approach

A very nice feature of `fc` is that if you just run `fc` command by itself, it will open text editor specified in`FCEDIT` variable (which you probably want stored in `~/.bashrc`) and the contents of the line will be your last command. For your ease, I suggest you use `nano` as your text editor, but if you know `vim`  - even better.

For example, what if I need to edit `qdbus org.ayatana.bamf  /org/ayatana/bamf/matcher org.ayatana.bamf.matcher.ActiveWindow` Huge line, right ? But with `fc`, I can open `vim` and edit `/org/ayatana/bamf/matcher` , save, exit and it will run.

Answer (score 9):

You can't use `!!` but ...

From the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-History-Builtins):

> A useful alias to use with the fc command is `r='fc -s'`, so that typing ‘r cc’ runs the last command beginning with cc **and typing ‘r’ re-executes the last command.**

Comment: So this will allow me to add something to the beginning of my last command. What about in the middle of it?

Answer (score 8):

If you insist on using the `!!` history expansion syntax instead of `fc` (mentioned already), there is a way.

By default, `history` expansion is disabled for non-interactive shell sessions e.g. in scripts.

To enable history expansion in scripts enable the relevant shell options first:

```
set -o history 
set -o histexpand
```

`set -o histexpand` can be written as `set -H` too.

Now the history expansion operations e.g. `!!` would work inside the script.