# Use previously run command as a properly-escaped argument

Tags: bash

A common use-case for me is to run a command in terminal, this command may be long, contain pipes `grep | awk | sort`, quotes of all sorts `'` `"`, escaped quotes within quotes `"\"somethings\""` etc.

But then it may turn out that I'll have to run this same command again and again. For simple commands I use `watch` like so

```
watch -n 5 'ls -l | wc -l'
```

But if the command is long and contains quotes it becomes very tedious and error-prone to properly escape everything before passing to `watch`.

Some shortcut or built-in way to get a properly-escaped string of the previous command would be nice. Is there any? I blindly tried `$ watch -n 5 !` and `$watch -n 5 '!'` but it wouldn't work.

Comment: `watch` command doesn't have any previous command history. Shell, however  does have `fc` command. Take a look at this post : http://askubuntu.com/a/800459/295286

Comment: Works like a charm! I used "PCMD=\`fc -nl -1\`; watch -n 5 $PCMD". Please post your answer as a proper answer so that I could accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although , `watch` doesn't have command history, shell history can use used for that purpose.  `fc -nl -1` allows listing previous commands executed by shell. One can do

```
PCMD=`fc -nl -1`; watch -n 5 $PCMD
```

Or even shorter

```
watch -n 5 $(fc -nl -1)
```

Example,

```
$> stat /etc/passwd                                                                                           
  File: '/etc/passwd'
  Size: 2989        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 801h/2049d  Inode: 6030444     Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2016-06-17 20:45:17.520447811 -0600
Modify: 2016-06-17 20:45:17.520447811 -0600
Change: 2016-06-17 20:45:17.528447711 -0600
 Birth: -
$> watch -n 5 $(fc -nl -1)
```